# My header() call is not redirecting to new page

Tags: php, html, redirect, header

I am having problems getting my page to redirect using the header method. I think I know what the problem is. But I am very new to the PHP scene so I don't know what else to try. From what I have read the header() method will not fire if a page has already sent data prior to the header. I feel this could be part of my problem because I have several echo statements before my header function. Could it be something else? How do I get around this?

An echo statement proves that the correct username and password are being located. I put a test echo statement where the header is, and it works just fine. So, I know the database is finding the correct information. The page refreshes when the info is inserted. Thanks for looking.

```
<div id= "sidebar" >
    <div id="login-box">    
        <form name="client-login" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"  method="post">
            <label id="user-lbl">Username:</label><br /><input type="text"
                name="username" id="username" /><br /> <label id="pass-lbl">Password:</label><br /><input
                type="password" name="password" id="password" /><br />     <label>&nbsp;</label><input
                type="submit" value="Login" class="submit" id="login" />
        </form>     
<?php 
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if((!isset($username)) || (!isset($password))){

    echo "<p>Username is $username. Password is $password.</p>";

     }else{

    $mysql = mysql_connect("myhost", "username", "password");
    if(!$mysql){
    echo "<p>Cannot connect to database!</p>";}
    $selected = mysql_select_db("mydb", $mysql);
    if(!$selected){
    echo "<p>Cannot find database!</p>";}

    $query = sprintf("SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE username = '%s' AND password = '%s'", mysql_real_escape_string($username),mysql_real_escape_string($password));

    $result = mysql_query($query, $mysql );
    if(!$result){
    echo "<p>Cannot run query.</p>";}

    $row  = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    $count = $row[0];
    if ($count > 0){
    header("Location: account.php"); die();} else {echo "<p>Invalid username or password!</p>";}
}  
?>

    </div><!-- #login-box -->
```

Comment: turn on `error_reporting(E_ALL)`. that will give you all the mistakes you made

Comment: RIGHT! And as you are very new to PHP, always keep turned ON error reporting during development. It will help you a lot.

Comment: @rabudde is this something I should put in each php page I work on? Do I need to make changes to the ini file? Know of any good literature? Php.net has a manual, but its a little intimidating. Thank you both for the tip!

Comment: I don't know a good literature for that. I learned all by doing. Turning on error_reporting is only good for development, not for production, but that helps me often on finding failures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you call `header()`, then it should be called **BEFORE**  any other function that prints an output to the HTML stream, OR before any HTML statements in that file. You cannot send even a newline character before the `header()` call.

Here in your case, first you are sending the `<div id= "sidebar" >` and other 7 lines to the client, and then only you are calling the `header()` function. That's why the error happened to you.

Reason:

The `header()` call is meant to deliver the HTTP header information to the client browser. The header information should be the **first** information to be sent to the client. If you are not calling the `header()` in your PHP script, the PHP will automatically send a header information just before sending the very first line of your PHP file.

Once a header is sent, you cannot send another header in the same PHP file. So, if you want to send a header exclusively, send it before any other body content starts.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response! I don't understand how I could put the header at the top of my page if it depends on information located from a variable. I could make a separate page but I like having my error messages display around my login fields. I tried moving everything as you suggested but the echo statements are still above it.

Comment: When using redirections using the `header()` function, the flow is like this :

Step 1: **FIRST OF ALL** check whether the user need to be redirected. If yes, then use `header()` to redirect.

Step 2: Start the page contents and other scripts.

In your case, you can **FIRST** start the PHP code, (which contains the `header()` call) and *AFTER THAT** you can write your `<div id= "sidebar">` code.

**IMPORTANT** - make sure that you are not echo-ing anything to the output stream just before you call `header()`. So, the **VERY FIRST** thing to do in your code is, processing the header statement.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's your problem.

The best solution for this is to have the code execute before you output anything to the browser. Barring that, adding `ob_start();` to the top of your script will buffer your output, allowing a `header();` call to work even after you've printed/echoed text.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! However, I added the function to the top inside a php block and outside a php block. Nothing happened. This is a wordpress site, so it's in chunks. Could that be a problem? For example. I am adding this code to my sidebar.php when in reality I am logging into my index.php page.

Answer (score 1):

By using php code:

```php
header('page url');
```

Using header may make problems while uploading to server.

By using javascript:

```js
window.location='page url';
```